# How to reset the loopback memory DB

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am running several loopback tests via `mocha` (let's call them `test1.js`, `test2.js` and `test3.js`).

When i run the independently everything works well. However, when I ask `mocha` to run them all, things that are created in the first test in the in-memory DB collide with tests being done later on (test 2 or 3).

Is there a way to ensure we start each test with an empty DB? Something like:

```
app.dataSources.db.reset()
```

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: What I ended up doing: I looked at the [DataSource](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler) code and found that you can do `automigrate` on the memory DB.

```
before("wipe DB (if used with other tests)", function(done) {
    app.dataSources.db.automigrate(function(err) {
        done(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a hold of the `db` via `app.dataSources.db` and execute `automigrate` as in:

```
before("wipe DB (if used with other tests)", function(done) {
    app.dataSources.db.automigrate(function(err) {
        done(err);
    });
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: Same thing here, I did replace `db` with my own mongo datasource but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: This didn't work for memory db if you choose to save it to file using file:"db.json", the question that was asked is how to reset the db after every test, and it turned out loopback keeps data in memory and then save it on that file to retrieve it back when it started again, I tried the mentioned solution but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should clean up after each test.

You can use [hooks](https://mochajs.org/#hooks), like `afterEach`

Comment: Thanks Yasei. That is what I resorted to right now, but some tests create a mess out of the memory DB and it's more expedient to just start from scratch. Cheers.